# Static and Kinetic Friction on an Incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

A box is launched upwards along a $30^o$ incline that is $1.0 m$ long. How far from the edge of the incline will the box reach if its initial speed is 3.55 m/s. The coefficients of of static and kinetic friction are $\mu_s = 0.30$ and $\mu_k = 0.20$.

I am having trouble with this type question in general, as I find it difficult to draw the free body diagram and then interpret the components in different directions.

*** UPDATE ***

This is what I have so far - I think I am 95% of the way there.

I note that there is no force pushing the box up once it has been launched, so the only two forces acting on it are the force of friction (kinetic, $\vec{F}_k$) and the component of gravity that is pulling down in the defined x direction (the same direction as $\vec{F}_k$). This is where I struggled most.

The normal force is perpendicular to the object, and is equal in magnitude, but points in the opposite direction to the force of gravity in the y-direction.

Then, the components of gravity are as follows:
$$\vec{F}_{G_y} = (m)(g)\cos \theta \implies N = (m)(g)\cos \theta$$
and 
$$\vec{F}_{G_x} = (m)(g)\sin \theta$$

From here, I understand that $\vec{F}_k = \mu_k(N) \implies \vec{F}_k = \mu_k (m)(g) \cos \theta$. Using kinetic friction since the object in question is in motion.

Then, $$\vec{F}_{net} = \vec{F}_{G_x} + \vec{F}_k = (m)(g)\sin \theta + \mu_k (m)(g) \cos \theta$$

Plugging in the numbers, I get $\vec{F}_{net} = (m)(-6.5974)$. From here I used $F = ma$ to get an acceleration of $-6.5974 \frac{m}{s^2}$.

Plugging in $v_f = 0 \frac{m}{s}$ and $v_i = 3.55 \frac{m}{s}$ into $(v_f)^2 = (v_i)^2 + 2ad$ I get $d$ equal to $0.95 m$.

However, the answer in the book is $0.05 m$ (which is conveniently 1 - my answer), so can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show  us your effort so far to draw the free body diagram and tell us what specific area is giving you problems? Without showing effort the question is sure to be closed (and there is no guarantee that it won't anyway since it is a homework and exercise type question.

Comment: Updated the question - I was having trouble starting, which is why I didn't post any of my work. I think I am almost there, just one small piece missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct, but you have calculated the distance the box travels from the *bottom* of the incline, which is $0.95$ m. Since the plane is $1$ m long, the box comes to rest $0.05$ m from the *top* of the incline - this must be what the question means when it says "How far from the edge of the incline will the box reach".

Answer (score 0):

Hint:) draw Fbd, there  are two forces which acts, along the incline that are $mgsinѲ$ and $f_k$ or $f_s$, that you need to think what type of friction is acting , and then  you  apply work energy Theorm,.